# Custom Model intended to be used for Curve Fitting. Vectorization vs For Loop and jit numba capabilities

Tags: python, matlab, vectorization, scipy, numba

I am new to community and please pardon me if I didn't provide information as intended.
This code is supposed to be creating a custom model which will be used with `lmfit` for curve fitting purposes. `hc(q,radius,pd)` is the function. It is one of the simplest functions that I will be using but even this function is taking quite a bit in python compared to Matlab. `q` values which are created for the sake of simplicity will be replaced by the experimental values and it will be used to fit the intensity from 1D SAXS results.
The difference between the vectorization and for loop is almost double. Although the documentation suggests to use for Loop, it gives slower results.

I am trying to learn Python, coming from Matlab. I have a very simple code for starting purposes:

```
from numpy import vectorize
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.special import j1
from math import sqrt, exp, pi, log
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import empty



def plot_hc(radius, pd):
    q = np.linspace(0.008, 1.0, num=500)
    y = hc(q, radius, pd)
    plt.loglog(q, y)
    plt.show()

def hc_formfactor(q, radius):
    y = (1.0 / q) * (radius * j1(q * radius))
    y = y ** 2
    return y

def g_distribution(z, radius, pd):
    return (1 / (sqrt(2 * pi) * pd)) * exp(
        -((z - radius) / (sqrt(
            2) * pd)) ** 2)


def ln_distribution(z, radius, pd):
    return (1 / (sqrt(2 * pi) * pd * z / radius)) * exp(
        -(log(z / radius) / (sqrt(2) * pd)) ** 2)

# Dist=1(for G_Distribution)
# Dist=2(for LN Distribution)
Dist = 1


@vectorize
def hc(x, radius, pd):
    global d
    if Dist == 1:
        nmpts = 4
        va = radius - nmpts * pd
        vb = radius + nmpts * pd
        if va < 0:
             va = 0
        d = integrate.quad(lambda z: g_distribution(z, radius, pd), va, vb)
    elif Dist == 2:
        nmpts = 4
        va = radius - nmpts * pd
        vb = radius + nmpts * pd
        if va < 0:
            va = 0
        d = integrate.quad(lambda z: ln_distribution(z, radius, pd), va, vb)
    else:
       d = 1

   def fun(z, x, radius, pd):
        if Dist == 1:
            return hc_formfactor(x, z) * g_distribution(z, radius, pd)
        elif Dist == 2:
            return hc_formfactor(x, z) * ln_distribution(z, radius, pd)
        else:
            return hc_formfactor(x, z)

    y = integrate.quad(lambda z: fun(z, x, radius, pd), va, vb)[0]
    return y/d[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot_hc(radius=40, pd=0.5)
```

As suggested in the documentation, I should use for loop, but that reduced the speed even more. The code using for loop is as follows:

```
from numpy import vectorize
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.special import j1
from math import sqrt, exp, pi, log
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import empty


def plot_hc(radius, pd):
    q = np.linspace(0.008, 1.0, num=500)
    y = hc(q, radius, pd)
    plt.loglog(q, y)
    plt.show()

def hc_formfactor(q, radius):
    y = (1.0 / q) * (radius * j1(q * radius))
    y = y ** 2
    return y

def g_distribution(z, radius, pd):
    return (1 / (sqrt(2 * pi) * pd)) * exp(
        -((z - radius) / (sqrt(
            2) * pd)) ** 2)


def ln_distribution(z, radius, pd):
    return (1 / (sqrt(2 * pi) * pd * z / radius)) * exp(
        -(log(z / radius) / (sqrt(2) * pd)) ** 2)

# Dist=1(for G_Distribution)
# Dist=2(for LN Distribution)
Dist = 1


def hc(q, radius, pd):
    if Dist == 1:
        nmpts = 4
        va = radius - nmpts * pd
        vb = radius + nmpts * pd
        if va < 0:
            va = 0
        d = integrate.quad(lambda z: g_distribution(z, radius, pd), va,vb)
    elif Dist == 2:
        nmpts = 4
        va = radius - nmpts * pd
        vb = radius + nmpts * pd
        if va < 0:
            va = 0
        d = integrate.quad(lambda z: ln_distribution(z, radius, pd), va, vb)
    else:
        d = 1

    def fun(z, q, radius, pd):
        if Dist == 1:
            return hc_formfactor(q, z) * g_distribution(z, radius, pd)
        elif Dist == 2:
            return hc_formfactor(q, z) * ln_distribution(z, radius, pd)
        else:
            return hc_formfactor(q, z)

    y = empty([len(q)])
    for n in range(len(q)):
        y[n] = integrate.quad(lambda z: fun(z, q[n], radius, pd), va, vb)[0]

    return y / d[0]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot_hc(radius=40, pd=0.5)
```

I don't understand, what should I do to optimise the code? If I run the same program for the same values in Matlab it is very fast. I don't know what mistake I did here. Also, some suggested to use jit from numba to speed up the integration, but I am not sure how to implement it. Please help :)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks a lot for your reply and for correcting me. Being a beginner, its always good to learn from the experts in the community. Thanks for the suggestions. I have edited the title as well as provided information in the text. Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: @Graipher Thanks a lot for your comment. It was a mistake I made when I copied and pasted the code.